# Why do Django REST Framework Renderer and Parsers have to be instantiated and do not offer their key methods as static/class methods?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, static-methods, class-method

Like Djangos rest_framework.JSONRenderer it needs to be instantiated like

```py
json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

in order to use the render method.

What's the background, that render() is not offered as a static/class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using static/class methods makes it impossible to override/hard to debug to use object specific tools such as adding instance variables if someone requires it.